# Date/Time validation with specific format

Tags: laravel, datetime, validation

I had problem validating date-time string in Laravel.

Here is a rule:

```
'time_in' => 'date_format:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm',
```

And here is an image of how it's actually written:
[image: datum]

By all account, it should work. What gives?

Comment: check exactly what is being submitted, not what is being shown in the input.

Comment: The format you are requesting be validated expects the date to look like `0606/MayMay/22222222 2323:0000` https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php
For the format specified, you should use @PunnyFlash's answer of `d/m/Y H:i`

Comment: @Herewegoagain Tried it. Just says in error string different validation format.

Comment: Are you able to share the input field ?

Comment: @Herewegoagain You can see on the image, input field and what is send to Laravel, in red error box. It's pretty much an "wysiwyg".

Comment: the error returned specifies `time out` however your rule is set to `time_in`. Wanted to confirm the input name fields match what the server is expecting

Comment: @Herewegoagain That because when i put `"time_in" => $request->time_in` in return response to see with me eyeballs, doesn't show other error response. Consider it there, since both "time_in" and "time_out" are written the same.

Comment: as @Flame suggested pls ```dd``` the ```request``` date and find out what is the actual date this is actually being sent to server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're describing format in a wrong way. Should be:

```php
'time_in' => 'date_format:d/m/Y H:i',
```

Comment: I copy pasted your validation. Didn't take either..

Answer (score 0):

```
date_format:format
```

The field under validation must match the given format. You should use either date or date_format when validating a field, not both. This validation rule supports all formats supported by PHP's DateTime class.

check laravel docs about validation rules : https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-date-format.